# Capture screenshot of iframe - html2canvas not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, html2canvas

I have the following iframe:

```
<iframe name="content" src="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 28px;" allowtransparency="true" border="0" scrolling="yes" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="90%" id="MyFrame"></iframe>
```

I simply want to capture a screenshot of the iframe contents as they stand, I've tried html2canvas but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried placing the iframe inside a div but no joy.

I've seen various methods of achieving this using php, but nothing that seems clear. Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 6):

It's written in the limitations section of the doc: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#limitations.

> The script doesn't render plugin content such as Flash or Java
>   applets. It doesn't render iframe content either.

Screen capture using JS raises security problems.

Recently I've been trying carota (https://github.com/danielearwicker/carota) with some success to render HTML text on a canvas. However, it only handles a small subset of HTML.

There is also the SVG `foreignobject`approach which makes it possible to render DOM objects in a canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Unfortunately, it is not implemented in IE, including IE 11.