# How to capture website url screen

Tags: iframe, screenshot, capture

I need to is possible to capture some url with javascript but not page where are you so just other url...

Etc. You are on infoinfo.com and here you need to show as a photo something from booking.com so is there a way to capture screen while you are not on the site you want to capture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture screenshot of iframe - html2canvas not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108487/capture-screenshot-of-iframe-html2canvas-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a screenshot service such as [Thumbalizr](http://thumbalizr.com/), [Browshot](https://browshot.com/) or [Url2Png](https://www.url2png.com/).

Comment: Yes thats I need but I need to build it myself... What is tehnlogy behind this services?

Comment: it depends on the service. Some use IE on Windows (!), other uses Firefox, Chromium Embedded Framework, PhantomJS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the browser, **no.** iFrames don't show up in page screenshots. Otherwise you could open someone's bank website in an iFrame and capture the data in an image.

Comment: what about server side?